# If questions/answers (before today) edited, than not showing active line

Tags: support

**Recently** I found that if Q/A edited (say:Today) than It should be active Today. But It is not showing line:

- [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465109/where-should-i-put-my-script) with active line:

[image: active-line]

- [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464651/problem-with-printing-hplip-in-ubuntu-14-04) without active line:

[image: no active-line]

**Even if it is edited today**:[image: edited]

Why it is not showing or is this option not available now?

Note:https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=active shows question as soon active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Activity" is everything other than it being posted.

- [Your first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465109/where-should-i-put-my-script) has answers from today, edits today and comments today. These all count as activity.
- [Your other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464651/problem-with-printing-hplip-in-ubuntu-14-04) has only been posted. That activity is implicit.

This is all part of the mechanism that decides what is how the front page is sorted.

Comment: Comments don't count towards activity. For example see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/435887/i-can-read-from-dev-null-how-to-fix-it), there was a comment today on the question itself, but it says that last activity was a month ago.

Comment: @Oli : my question-http://askubuntu.com/questions/464651/problem-with-printing-hplip-in-ubuntu-14-04 has now comment also today but it still not showing active today. So, I think **Question should have answer** then it shows active today!